# Inkscape extensions not working

Tags: python, plugins, software-design, vector-graphics, inkscape

I installed inkscape and some plugins today for my laser engraver.

I copied extension files to both directories (if i only copy one directory, extensions don't seen properly in program menu):

C:\Users\Alen Geere\AppData\Roaming\inkscape\extensions

C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\extensions

In program, i don't get any error when i try to open extensions. Nothing.

But when i checked the extension-error text file, i found something:

```
Extension "DXF Input" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: ex

ecutable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "About" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Area" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Check for updates" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "DXF Points" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Engraving" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Graffiti" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Lathe" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Orientation points" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Path to Gcode" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Prepare path for plasma" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Tools library" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "J Tech Photonics Laser Tool" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py

Extension "Raster 2 Laser GCode generator" failed to load because a dependency was not met.
Dependency:
  type: executable
  location: extensions
  string: inkex.py
```

What's going on? I read about python and environment variable in windows on the web. I install python's latest version and added path info to variables. Could you help me please? Thanks.

I use Windows 7 64
Inkscape 0.92
Gcodetools extension
j tech photonics laser tool extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the main extension file that comes with Inkscape is missing.

The easiest way to fix this without needing to do any manual copying from the Inkscape code repository is to uninstall Inkscape, then reinstall a current version from the inkscape.org website.

The extension should be put into the folder that is listed at Edit > Preferences > System > User extensions. Putting them in the /share folder will remove it when updating Inkscape.